# How to increase insert of records into RDS MySQL more efficiently and fastly using JDBC API

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement, amazon-rds

I'm trying to insert nearly 200,000 records reading from a CSV file to RDS (MySQL) using a Lambda function. The time taken to insert completely is nearly 10 mins which is very concerning. I would like to know how to increase the speed for insertion.

Techniques I tried :

1. Using Prepared Statement for batch insertion like below code :

   ```
   BufferedReader lineReader =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.defaultCharset()));//inputStream is data from csv file
    try (PreparedStatement batchStatement = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_QUERY)) {//connection is JDBC connection instance
        LOGGER.debug("Processing Insert");
        Stream<String> lineStream = lineReader.lines().skip(1);
        List<String> collect = lineStream.collect(Collectors.toList());
        for (String line : collect) {
            String[] data = line.split(",", -1);
            batchStatement.setString(1, data[0]);
            //remaining code of setting data
            batchStatement.addBatch();
            batchStatement.executeBatch();
            batchStatement.clearBatch();
        }

        batchStatement.executeBatch();
        connection.commit();

    } catch(exception e){
        //throw exception code
    }finally{
        lineReader.close();
        connection.close();
    }
   ```
2. Implemented rewritebatchedstatements=true in connection URL

Please suggest if anything is feasible in this case for faster inserting data into RDS (MySQL).

Comment: just wondering why you are executing the batch in each iteration inside your for loop?

Comment: Got suggestion from various forums about this way like in this link  :https://www.codejava.net/coding/java-code-example-to-insert-data-from-csv-to-database .

Comment: they only execute it within the if statement and only when it reaches some size. check the code again.

Answer (score 1):

Only execute the batch in chunks, such as 100 at a time not one at a time as you have it now:

```
int rows = 0; // outside the loop
...
if((++rows % 100) == 0) {
     batchStatement.executeBatch();
}
// Don't reset the batch as this will wipe the 99 previous rows:
//batchStatement.clearBatch();
```

Also: changing auto commit mode will improve bulk updates, remember to reset back afterwards if not using addBatch or if connections are re-used:

```
connection.setAutoCommit(false);
```

Comment: Given the OP has `connection.commit()` in their code, they already disabled auto-commit (otherwise that statement will throw an exception).

Comment: row++ % 100 , looks like invalid type expecting boolean but provided int. If you meant if(row++ % 100 == 0){}, SONAR will complain as this condition will be always true. Correct me if the understanding is wrong

Comment: @Rajesh_iLearn Yes my `if` logic isn't right as I'm not with my PC. I intended that the execute runs every 100 rows. You should experiment with how many rows are suitable and possibly whether to `commit` periodically if appropriate for your transactions.

Answer (score 0):

1. `LOAD DATA INFILE` into a separate table, `t1`.
2. Cleanse the data.  That is, fix anything that needs modification, perform normalization, etc.
3. `INSERT INTO real table (...) SELECT ... FROM t1`.

If you need further discussion, please provide, *in SQL*, the table schema and any transforms needed by my step 2.  Also, a few rows of sample data may help.